# Best way to override auto-mocks?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I need all module functions to be auto-mocked except those I want to mock manually.
I'd like to do this using factory parameter of jest.mock() by analogy with an example from jest docs (https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename), something like this:

```
jest.mock('someModule', () => ({
  ...jest.requireMock('someModule'), // This doesn't work :(
  someFunction: jest.fn(() => 'someValue')
}));
```

I expect jest.requireMock(moduleName) to do the trick like jest.requireActual(moduleName) does, but end up with
`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Is it possible to achieve my goal in such a manner?
If no, what is the best practice of doing this?

jest: 24.9.0, ts-jest: 26.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jest.mock` is either automatic or manual, it cannot be both.

Auto-mock can be created with `jest.createMockFromModule` and then extended. This is useful in reusable mocks in `__mocks__` but generally not needed on test level.

Unless a mock is used on import time and needs to be hosted, a way to do this per test suite is:

```
jest.mock('someModule');

beforeEach(() => {
  someModule.someFunction.mockReturnValue('someValue')
});
```

> I expect jest.requireMock(moduleName) to do the trick

This shouldn't be expected because a mock is imported inside a mock, this results in a recursion.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Replacing `jest.requireMock` with `jest.createMockFromModule` in my example helped. Sometimes it is convenient to switch from auto-mocks to actual data and vice versa and the approach from example allows to do this with a single line change.